# Parsing complex nested JSON in Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I want to parse a Billionaires JSON dataset into Pig.The JSON file can be found [here](https://think.cs.vt.edu/corgis/json/billionaires/billionaires.html).

Here is what each entry has:

```
{
    "wealth": {
        "worth in billions": 1.2,
        "how": {
             "category": "Resource Related",
             "from emerging": true,
             "industry": "Mining and metals",
             "was political": false,
             "inherited": true,
             "was founder": true
         },
         "type": "privatized and resources"
    },
    "company": {
        "sector": "aluminum",
        "founded": 1993,
        "type": "privatization",
        "name": "Guangdong Dongyangguang Aluminum",
        "relationship": "owner"
        },
    "rank": 1372,
    "location": {
          "gdp": 0.0,
          "region": "East Asia",
          "citizenship": "China",
          "country code": "CHN"
              },
    "year": 2014,
    "demographics": {
              "gender": "male",
              "age": 50
              },
    "name": "Zhang Zhongneng"
}
```

**Attempt 1**

I tried loading this data using the following command in grunt :

> billionaires = LOAD 'billionaires.json' USING JsonLoader('wealth:
>   (worth in billions:double, how: (category:chararray, from
>   emerging:chararray, industry:chararray, was political:chararray,
>   inherited:chararray, was founder:chararray), type:chararray), company:
>   (sector:chararray,founded:int,type:chararray,name:chararray,relationship:chararray),rank:int,location:(gdp:double,region:chararray,citizenship:chararray,country
>   code:chararray), year:int, demographics: (gender:chararray,age:int),
>   name:chararray');

This however gives me the error:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input 'in' expecting RIGHT_PAREN

**Attempt 2**

Next I tried using Twitter's elephantbird project's loader called `com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader`. [Here](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/blob/master/pig/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/load/JsonLoader.java) is the code for this UDF. This is what I did:

```
billionaires = LOAD 'billionaires.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map[]);
names = foreach billionaires generate json#'name' AS name;
dump names;
```

Now this runs and I get no errors! But nothing gets displayed. I get an output like:

> Input(s): Successfully read 0 records (1445335 bytes) from:
>   "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/purak/billionaires.json"
>
> Output(s): Successfully stored 0 records in:
>   "hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp-1399280624/tmp-477607570"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1478889184960_0005

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best way of doing this but this is what I end up doing :

1. *Remove spaces from the field names* : I replaced fields like "worth in billions", "from emerging" etc with "worth_in_billions", "from_emerging" etc in the json dataset. (I did a simple 'find and replace' for this)
2. *Comma delimited json to newline delimited json* : The json file that I had was of the form `[{"_comment":"first entry" ...},{"_comment":"second entry" ...}]`. But JsonLoader in Pig takes each newline to be a new entry. To make the json file newline delimited instead of comma I used [js](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which is a command-line JSON processor. Install it using `sudo apt-get install js` and run `cat billionaires.json | jq -c ".[]" > newBillionaires.json`.
3. The newBillionaires.json file now has each entry on new line. Now load this file into Pig using:

   `copyFromLocal /home/purak/Desktop/newBillionaires.json /user/purak`

> billionaires = LOAD 'newBillionaires.json' USING
>   JsonLoader('name:chararray, demographics:
>   (age:int,gender:chararray),year:int,location:(country_code:chararray,citizenship:chararray,region:chararray,gdp:double),rank:int,company:
>   (relationship:chararray,name:chararray,type:chararray,founded:int,sector:chararray),
>   wealth:(type:chararray,how:(was_founder:chararray,inherited:chararray,was_political:chararray,industry:chararray,
>   from_emerging:chararray,category:chararray),worth_in_biilions:double)');

*Note*: Using js reversed the order of fields in each entry. Hence in the load command all fields are in a reversed order compared to the load command in the question.

4. You can now unnest each tuples using :

> billionairesFinal = foreach billionaires generate name,
>   demographics.age as age, demographics.gender as gender, year,
>   location.country_code as countryCode, location.citizenship as
>   citizenship, location.region as region, location.gdp as gdp, rank,
>   company.relationship as companyRelationship, company.name as
>   companyName, company.type as companyType, company.founded as
>   companyFounded, company.sector as companySector, wealth.type as
>   wealthType, wealth.how.was_founder as wasFounder, wealth.how.inherited
>   as inherited, wealth.how.was_political as wasPolitical,
>   wealth.how.industry as industry, wealth.how.from_emerging as
>   fromEmerging, wealth.how.category as category,
>   wealth.worth_in_biilions as worthInBillions;

5. Check the structure once using `describe billionairesFinal;` :

> billionairesFinal: {name: chararray,age: int,gender: chararray,year:
>   int,countryCode: chararray,citizenship: chararray,region:
>   chararray,gdp: double,rank: int,companyRelationship:
>   chararray,companyName: chararray,companyType:
>   chararray,companyFounded: int,companySector: chararray,wealthType:
>   chararray,wasFounder: chararray,inherited: chararray,wasPolitical:
>   chararray,industry: chararray,fromEmerging: chararray,category:
>   chararray,worthInBillions: double}

This was the intended structure of data that I wanted in Pig! Now I can ahead on and analyse the dataset :)